# Simple SQL select sum one time and values of same column

Tags: mysql

I have create this query:

```
SELECT table1.id, b.sum 
FROM table1 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(id) sum 
            FROM table1) b 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

But this produces results like this:

| id | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 |

Sum value print only one time. Can you help me.

But I want this result :

| id | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 |
| 2 |  |
| 1 |  |

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select 
   id,
   CASE WHEN id=(max(id) over()) 
        THEN sum(id) over (order by id) END as 'sum' 
from cte1
order by id desc;
```

more info see: [Window Function Concepts and Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)